# Lebesgue outer measure of product of sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $\lambda^\ast$ be the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\lambda^\ast_2$ the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, defined as the infimum of the sum of the rectangles covering a set.
Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be subsets such that $\lambda^\ast(A)=\infty$ and $\lambda^\ast(B)>0$. Then is it true that $\lambda^\ast_2(A\times B)=\infty$ ?
It seems intuitively obvious, but I can't seem to prove it. I would prefer a proof which is as elementary as possible.

Comment: If you know product measure and that the lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ is equal to the product of the lebesgue measures restricted to the product sigma algebra, then there is nothing to prove. So, you can search for the proof that product of lebesgue measures results in the lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ and it should essentially show you that $\lambda_{2}^{*}(A\times B)=\lambda^{*}(A)\times \lambda^{*}(B)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is true for any sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, but I think I can prove it when $A$ and $B$ are Lebesgue-measurable. The idea is that  we first prove
\begin{equation}
\lambda(A\times B)=\lambda(A)\lambda(B)
\tag{$\ast$}\label{ab}
\end{equation}
when $\lambda(A)<\infty$ and $\lambda(B)<\infty$. Then
with $A_n=A\cap[-n,n]$ and $B_n=B\cap[-n,n]$,
$$\lambda(A\times B)=\lambda\left(\bigcup_n(A_n\times B_n)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(A_n\times B_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(A_n)\lambda(B_n)=\infty.$$
To prove \eqref{ab} when $\lambda(A)<\infty$ and $\lambda(B)<\infty$, we first prove
$$\lambda(A\times B)\leq\lambda(A)\lambda(B),$$
which follows easily from the definition of outer measure. (In fact, it holds even when $A$ or $B$ is not Lebesgue-measurable.) Here is a [link](https://math.solverer.com/library/terence_tao/an_introduction_to_measure_theory/exercise_1-2-22?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link) for the proof.
For the opposite inequality, we first prove it when $A$ and $B$ are open sets, then use the regularity of Lebesgue-measurable sets. The same link shows a proof, although it contains some errors, which can be easily fixed.